# Why is Jest marking as uncovered data retrieved from the theme provider?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, styled-components

I'm using Jest's theme provider to get some font sizes and colors in my styled component, however the lines where I use the theme provider (from styled-components) are reported as uncovered in the test.

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Container = styled.div`
   & > div {
      margin-top: 6px;
      font-size: ${p=> p.theme.fontsize.quote};
      color: ${p => p.theme.colors.red};
   }
`
```

Why are those lines uncovered?

Comment: make sure, you are using this Container, somewhere in the react component,
if you are using in some react component ideally it should be covered in code coverage

Comment: the Container component is in use by another component, its not being covered